# Why is this code more efficient than than mine?

Tags: python, performance, set

I am learning how to do python using this website using HankerRank. I came across [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/py-the-captains-room/problem?isFullScreen=false) and the code that I wrote didn't pass a few tests due to a the time limit being exceeded. So I went on youtube and used a tutorial and his code worked but I don't understand why his code is more efficient than mine. If someone could explain it'll be greatly appreciated.

My Code:

```
room=list(map(int, input().split()))
room.sort()
roomset=set(room.copy())

for i in roomset:
    if room.count(i)!=K:
        print(i)
    else:
        continue
```

Tutorial's Code:

```
room=list(map(int, input().split()))
room.sort()
a=set()
b=set()

for i in room:
    if i not in a:
        a.add(i)
        b.add(i)
    else:
        b.discard(i)
        
for o in b:
    print(o)
```

Comment: `room.count(i)` is O(n) for the size of room

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code is slow is because in each iteration of your loop, python needs to scan the entire list to count how many times the number appears. This means that in the worst case, the number of operations grows with the square of the input size, which makes it take a long time.

The tutorial's code just keeps a set of numbers that have been encountered at least once (`a`), and a set of numbers that have been encountered exactly once (`b`). The set operations to insert, delete, and check for membership are all constant time, so their algorithm's time grows linearly with the length of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Time exceeded means you are doing more work than required.

`room.sort()` - why do you `sort` the list of room numbers? The code does not take any advantage of it. (strange, the other code does this too, did I overlooked something?)

`roomset=set(room.copy())` - no need to make a copy

But the main problem is that the question is not: **how many times is a room number present in the list?**, but rather: **is it exactly 1?**. If you encounter a room number for the second time, you have an answer and you should stop counting.

The more efficient code does just that. It remembers if it has seen a room number (set `a`) and if it is the first occurence (set `b`). No counting, i.e. it is sufficient to go through the list just once - that is an important efficiency improvement. After examining all numbers, the set `b` contains only item(s) with exactly one occurence.

Answer (score 0):

Because **For loop** and **room.count(i)** gives O(n) * O(n) = O(n**2) time complexity. While tutorial solution equals O(n)